# Calling Directive method from Controller : AngularJS

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-directive, controller

I have created a directive like the following

```
.directive("sampleInstructionOne",['$q' , '$rootScope',  'HigiKioskStorageService', 'HigiKioskUtilitiesService',function($q, $rootScope, HigiKioskStorageService,HigiKioskUtilitiesService) {
    //Weight instruction 1
    return {
        restrict : 'E',
        scope : false,
        templateUrl : 'components/weight/ecg-instruction-1.html',
        link : function(scope, element, attr){
            scope.weightInstruction = scope.weightInstruction || new Object();
            scope.weightInstruction.isHigi= HigiKioskUtilitiesService.isHigiGreen();

            scope.weightInstruction.bmcAnimationOne = function(){
                var q = $q.defer();
                $('.bmc_instruction_place').css('opacity', 1);
                $('#bmc_instruction_place_frames').delay(50)//we don't want to use a timeout, so we use a delay
                    .animate({'backgroundPosition':'left top'}, 1, function () { //a dummy function to "restart" the animation at first frame AND have a callback where we set the sprite
                        $('#bmc_instruction_place_frames').sprite({ //sets the sprite and animates it immediately
                            fps:(scope.weightInstruction.isHigi) ? 24 : 18,
                            no_of_frames:(scope.weightInstruction.isHigi) ? 24 : 18,
                            start_at_frame:0,
                            play_frames:(scope.weightInstruction.isHigi) ? 24 : 18
                        });
                    })
                    .delay(2000)//a delay to wait until the sprite animation is completed. this number needs to be equal to how long the sprite animates
                    .animate({'backgroundPosition':'right top'}, 1, function () { //a dummy function to house the callback, but also to make sure the animation is at the last frame
                        q.resolve();
                        $('#bmc_instruction_place_frames').destroy(); //you MUST destroy the sprite if you want it to play again
                    });

                return q;
            };
            scope[attr.promisename].resolve();

        }
    }
}])
```

I need to call the directive method 'scope.weightInstruction.bmcAnimationOne" in controller . I have tried calling like the following and ended up with "Cannot read property bmcAnimationOne undefined".

```
 $scope.instructionTwo = [
            $scope.weightInstruction.bmcAnimationOne
        ];
```

Comment: This is probably because the scope in the controller is not the same one as the scope in the directive. Are we talking about the controller that goes with the directive? Could you share some more code, like the controller code and the code that ties the controller to the directive?

Answer (score 0):

When you're trying to access *$scope.weightInstruction.bmcAnimationOne* in the parent controller, since *bmcAnimation* is a promise, probably it hasn't finished yet, so for the controller point of view, it isn't defined yet.

You should wait until it's loaded, then assign the result:

```
$scope.instructionTwo = [];
$scope.weightInstruction.bmcAnimationOne()
    .then(function (result) {
        $scope.instructionTwo.push(result));
    }
}
```